# Partitioning and Performance of DB Table

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning

After partitioning a table the performance of select queries returning large datasets degrades as compared to performance earlier. For small datasets there is no degradation. No change in index is done.What can be reason and is it normal?

An obfuscated/sample query is:

```
Select * from Table where code >123
```

Table is partitioned on column `code`.

@paul white , I am asking the reason why this query is slow after partitioning on column of filtering condition.

Due to reason I cannot share the query but query and indexes remain same before and after partitioning on a code column. What can be possible reasons?

Moreover, after partitioning the slowed query use more than one partition but it is not somehow avoidable.

Partitioning is Hash based wrapper over table (not b-tree) independent of the internal structure of table. Please correct me if I am wrong with ref.

Comment: Slower performance may be expected depending on your table and query. Partitioning is mostly a manageability feature can negatively impact performance if not done thoughtfully. Add your query and DDL to your question, [upload the actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), and include the link for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Indexes are not really the same after partitioning a table because the partitioning column is (at least) implicitly included for the row locator. It might be that all partitions are touched because the partitioning column isn't specified in a query predicate. If you can't post the actual DDL and query, at least provide an obfuscated version if you need a good answer.

Comment: How many partitions in the table? Is there an index on code? Is it the leading column of the index(es). Are the indexes clustered or non-clustered? Are the indexes aligned? What is the data type of the code column? To avoid downvotes (which does not include me yet), make an effort to include pertinent information in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partitioning's primary purpose is not performance, but management of large amounts of data. By partitioning data, you are actually spreading it across [multiple data structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189051(v=sql.105)) (such as B-trees), and likely increasing the amount of operations required to retrieve that data for your queries.

The scenario where partitioning can help is called partition elimination, where your query is designed in such a way that SQL Server can guarantee it only needs to access some of those many B-trees (or other storage structures) you built. Some more information on that [here](https://littlekendra.com/2015/11/17/did-my-query-eliminate-table-partitions-sql-server/).

Just like `NOLOCK`, partitioning is not a magic "go-faster" setting. You need to understand what it's doing and why you're using it.

Comment: Most tables in SQL Server are stored as BTrees, although it also supports storing tables as a Heap, a Clustered Columnstore, or an In-Memory Table.

Comment: Conceptually all tables in SQL Server are partitioned, although some have only a single partition.